# Cookies, objects and JSON

Tags: javascript, json, cookies

Is it possible to stringify an object and then save it locally in a cookie, then retrieve it and parse it to revert it back to normal the next time the user logs on?

Tried to cram it all into once sentence. Here's an example of what I meant:

```
var theObject = {
    oProp : 10,
    oProp : true
};

var jString = JSON.stringify(theObject);
createCookie("object", jString);
var objectRetrieved = JSON.parse( readCookie("object") );

theObject = objectRetrieved;
```

If this is possible, what about storing each of the objects property/values individually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If your goal is to store the data for longer than one session, I believe you can use the localStorage API which requires you to stringify the data and you would have to parse it as you want when retrieving it back. If you need data only for the duration of the session, you could use the sessionStorage API. To answer your question, yes it is possible and it's also possible to store each key value pair separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use jquery here is a cleaner approach to this-

Don't explicitly say `JSON.Stringify`.Instead of that you can set `$.cookie.json = true;`

Then store the object to cookie.

```
var myObj= { //what ever your properties }
$.cookie('myObj', myObj);
```

When reading back from cookie I would do

```
var myObj = $.cookie('myObj');
alert('Property name is ' + myObj.YourPropertyName);
```

Comment: The question does not mention jQuery at all. Also, the `$.cookie.json` API was a mistake. See the discussion [here](https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie/pull/285). I would not encourage people to use that. Instead, I would suggest using `stringify` or upgrading to the latest minor [version 1.5.1](https://github.com/js-cookie/js-cookie/releases/tag/v1.5.1) which introduces a better and understandable API to handle JSON.

Answer (score 1):

Just as an alternative to cookie method, you can also use local storage like so:

```
var myObj = {"name":"n1","val":3,"bool":true};
localStorage.setItem('save', JSON.stringify(myObj));
var tmp = localStorage.getItem('save');
var round_trip = JSON.parse(tmp)
```